# Rails has many through association setting multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

So I have a `has_many through` association where between two tables `posts` and `users`:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end 

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :posts, :through => :assignments
end 

class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now in my association table (`assignment`) there are additional attributes for `creator:boolean` and `editor:boolean`.

My question is what's the best way to set these secondary attributes from within the controller?

Having looked around I've got a current solution:

`posts_controller.rb`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    params.permit!
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save    
      Assignment.handle_post(@post.id, params[:creator], params[:editors])
      redirect_to posts_path, notice: "The post #{@post.title} has been created."
    else
      render "new"
    end
end
```

`assignment.rb`:

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :user

  def self.handle_post(post_id, creator, assignment)
    Assignment.where(:post_id => post_id).delete_all

    Assignment.create!(:post_id => post_id, :user_id => creator, :creator => true, :editor => false)

    if editors.present?
      editors.each do |e| 
        Assignment.create!(:post_id => post_id, :user_id => e, :creator => false, :editor => true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So what is essentially happening is I'm getting the user_ids from the form via `params` (`creator` returns 1 id, `editors` returns an array), and AFTER creating the post I'm deleting all columns associated with the post and recreating them off the new attributes.

The issue I have here is I can't run `post` validations on these associations (e.g. check a creator is present).

My two questions are as follows:

1. Is this the correct way to handle secondary attributes?
2. Is there a way to set the association up and then save it all at once so validations can be performed?

Comment: What do you mean by "set the association up"? Do you mean create a post and associations at the same time?

Comment: Yes, but in essence I'm just trying to figure out how to run validations on `post` which rely on the associations.

Comment: You have a has_many through on which objects?

Comment: Added the three models to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more Rails way to do this:

**Use nested attributes**

*post.rb*

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  has_many :assignments, inverse_of: :post
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments

  # Your logic
end
```

*assignment.rb*

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_editors

  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :assignments

  # I would create attribute accessors to handle the values passed to the model
  attr_accessor :editors

  # Your validations go here
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  # Your logic

  private

  def set_editors
    # you can perform deeper vaidation here for the editors attribute
    if editors.present?
      editors.each do |e|
        Assignment.create!(post_id: post_id, user_id: e, creator: false, editor: true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And finally, add this to your PostsController

```
params.require(:post).permit(..., assignments_attributes: [...])
```

This allows you to create Assignments from the create Post action, will run validations on Post and Assignment and run callbacks for you.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Totally forgot about callbacks (despite using them in other parts of my app), thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I can help!

Comment: Quick question, does `attr_accessor :editors` refer to the `params[:editors]` in the post controller?  I'm just having a little trouble following logic of the controller.  Where does `post_id` and `user_id` in `assignment.rb` come from? Are they passed by the strong_params?

Comment: Assignment belongs both to post and user. So, Assignment has both methods post_id and user_id

Comment: And yes, the `attr_accessor :editors` refers to `params[:editors]`

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification. If I'm using the `after_create` hook, won't the `set_editors` `create!` method try and create an `assignment` which already exists? AKA they'll be two rows with the same post and user ids, and one with `editor: true` and one without?

Comment: You need to set default values for creator and editor. This way, if you don't have an `editors` your code is 'dryer'. Also, when you will run the set_editors, you will create multiple assignments belonging to the same `post`, but to different users `..., user_id: e, ...` in the `create!` method.